# Can not modify request headers via chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, browser, header

My main aim is to modify the origin header to some specific origin, but I am unable to modify any header of the request.

I tried with **onBeforeSendHeaders** event listener with **extraHeaders** option

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener((details) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
        if (details.requestHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'origin') {
            details.requestHeaders[i].value = "https://bar.com"
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(details);
    return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
}, {
    urls: [
        "https://*.foo.com/*"
    ]
}, ['extraHeaders', 'requestHeaders']);
```

Later I also tried changing the user-agent header with the code provided in the documentation - https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#examples

but none of it worked, headers are getting changed in the logged object but

then I logged the headers with onSendHeaders event listener with this code

```
chrome.webRequest.onSendHeaders.addListener((details) => {

    console.log("Header sent", details)
}, {
    urls: [
        "https://*.foo.com/*"
    ]
}, ['extraHeaders', 'requestHeaders']);
```

and it shows none of the headers changed.

I am not using any other extension (disabled all).
I am using manifest version 3 and I have these permissions

```
"permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "scripting",
        "webRequest"
],
"host_permissions": [
        "https://*.foo.com/*",
        "https://*.bar.com/*"
]
```

My Browser : Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)

My OS: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: To modify a request you need to add `'blocking'` to the last parameter. And `"webRequestBlocking"` to permissions in manifest.json, see the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried this, it gives one warning that "webRequestBlocking" requires manifest version 2 or lower. But still doesn't work. Should I move to manifest version 2?

Comment: ManifestV3 has killed WebRequestBlocking so either use declarativeNetRequest or ManifestV2.